# Authentication Error: Software can't be installed or removed | You are not allowed to perform this action

Tags: permissions, software-center

I have checked on other forums for the answer to this problem but I still can't seem to find a fix. I cannot install anything from software center. It says that I don't have the permissions. I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you admin or the owner of the system? Run `sudo -l` and let see the results.

Comment: Did you forgot your password?

Comment: Yes I am the owner of the system and no I have not forgotten the password

Comment: @AlaskanPorcupine Are you still having this problem? If you open a Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), type/paste in `groups` (just that word) and press Enter, what does it show? Does it list `sudo`? If so, does `sudo echo success` print "success" or give an error message? How about `pkexec echo success`? (You'll have to enter your password for the `sudo` and `pkexec` commands.) Please then **[edit]** your question, copy all text from the terminal--it shouldn't include the text of your password--and paste it in. You can then select the text you pasted and press Ctrl+K or click **{}** to format it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a suggestion to run this from the terminal:

```
gksu software-center
```

It will open the Software Center and I was then able to install programs. It will ask for a password before opening center.

Comment: Same command can be made into a launcher to allow launching the software center with a click and being prompted for password.